# Send list of files via Spring Boot controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have the following controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/url", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public List<ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>> getLayouts(@RequestParam("app") String app, HttpServletResponse response) {
.....
                inputStreamResource = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file));               
                HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
                responseHeaders.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/xml");
                responseHeaders.setContentLength(file.length());
                responseHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
                ResponseEntity inputStreams = new ResponseEntity(inputStreamResource, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
                inputStreamResources.add(inputStreams);
.....
        }
```

So the problem is that it doesn't work. First I had the problem:

```
No serializer found for class java.io.FileDescriptor 
and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer 
(to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) )
```

Then I added:

```
objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, Visibility.NONE);
objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
```

And problem disappeared, but arise the new one: I see that my inputStream repeated many times and now I have an error:

```
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
```

My question what's wrong I do or missed something? Is there better way to send list of files, maybe my approach is wrong in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends what you want to do, if you want to return paths and content then I would return something like `ResponseEntity<List<FileResource>>` where `FileResource` would be your own class:

```
public class FileResource {
    private String fileName;
    private byte[] content;
    // getters, setters
}
```

But be aware though that this approach may consume a lot of memory and also result in huge responses - for larger files you may want to return only a list of file names and then let the client request the files one by one, whereupon you'd stream the file content directly to output. Or you could zip the files in a single archive and return the archive to the client (like many cloud storages do).

You may also want to look at https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/

Comment: So do you think that I can't send list of files with InputStreamResource, because I already can send one file?

Comment: Well, you have a problem because you are using streams and Jackson does not have very good support for them. Especially since in your particular case there is a circular reference between a file input stream and it's file descriptor. Also, instead of sending a list of ResponseEntity objects you should really send a ResponseEntity with a List payload. Plus, I guess you really want to send file content to the client, therefore byte array makes more sense. 
You can send a list of files but most of the services out there don't - and I think for a good reason.

Comment: Sorry if that sounds confusing :)